# HANA: SQL Trigger to set a row's last modified date?

Tags: sql, triggers, hana

So, I understand how to create a trigger in HANA, but the examples in the [HANA reference material](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d5a65575191014946db96aaedbef5b/content.htm) do not mention how a trigger on Table A can update Table A; instead the material is always trigger on A updates B like the following example from the SAP docs:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER_VAR_UPDATE                   
AFTER UPDATE ON TARGET                                   
REFERENCING NEW ROW mynewrow, OLD ROW myoldrow          
FOR EACH ROW                                             
BEGIN                                                    
    INSERT INTO SAMPLE_new VALUES(:mynewrow.a, :mynewrow.b); 
    INSERT INTO SAMPLE_old VALUES(:myoldrow.a, :myoldrow.b);
    INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES(0, 'trigger');
END;
```

What's the preferred way of updating a column such as a LastModifiedDate? Would I set `:mynewrow.LastModifiedDate = NOW()`, or should I perform an `UPDATE` where the ID matches the ID of `mynewrow`?

Comment: This is looking grim.... "It is noted in the forums and by SAP Techs that trigger functionality for [Last Modified Date] is not supported" http://scn.sap.com/thread/3657168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of SPS8, a HANA SQL Trigger can only perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements against *other* tables. If you try to create a self-referencing Trigger, you'll find the following error message:

```
Modification of subject table in trigger not allowed
```

Comment: Does that apply to secondary triggers on the target table that conditionally write back to the originial subject table?